# Checking Datadog agent versions installed on AWS EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, datadog

Recent Tenable scan highlighted an issue with certain versions of datadog versions. This is also brought to attention in Datadog monitor.

Critical bug in Windows Agent versions 6.14.0 and 6.14.1. See --> http://dtdg.co/win-614-fix <-- for steps to fix the issue.

As the bulk of our servers are hosted on AWS - just wondered if I could query this through AWS CLI to list which servers were using the affected versions.

Comment: No you can't, the AWS CLI does not provide this functionality.  I'd suggest looking into an automation tool (e.g. Ansible or Chef) to perform this function.

Comment: Thanks kenlukas. Have just started learning anisible for future tool for deployment -- might repost to see if anyone has done something similar and whether there are any playbooks that would give me an idea of how to extract these details.

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of the infrastructure list, you should see a link called "JSON API permalink". If you [query it](https://app.datadoghq.com/reports/v2/overview), this should give you a JSON of all your hosts with their agent version. You can then query it with a quick Python script.

Comment: This is the right idea, but you'll want to make sure you use the `with_meta=true` in order to get the "agent_version" values in the response. [Here's a doc that describes the api in more detail.](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/guide/query-the-infrastructure-list-via-the-api/#overview) And you can run this API call in your browser ([link](https://app.datadoghq.com/reports/v2/overview?with_meta=true)) and just plug it into a JSON parser if you like.